# What causes this error in Proguard: "Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called"?

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I am running Proguard via the Maven Plugin, you can see my configuration here: https://github.com/sanity/tahrir/blob/proguard-debug/pom.xml#L61

You can see the complete output of "mvn -DskipTests assembly:assembly" here: https://gist.github.com/ee1081179496e11916cb

Despite quite a bit of searching I cannot find any explanation of what causes this error, nor now I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input contains a library class that depends on a program class. ProGuard warns about it and doesn't allow it, unless you specify `-dontwarn`. You should remove that option and check ProGuard's warnings for details.

See the ProGuard manual > [Introduction](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/introduction.html)

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: library class ... depends on program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

Answer (score 0):

For me, having

```
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
```

caused the same error.
Correcting to include both sdk and my config file like below fixed it.

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```