# "Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called" in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

Getting following error while exporting **Android** app on **Eclipse**.

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Note: there were 157 duplicate class definitions.
You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Error: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called
```

Any idea what could cause this?
Is the `ClassMerger` error messages related to the the duplicate class definitions warning above?

As mentioned on [What causes this error in Proguard: "Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388167/what-causes-this-error-in-proguard-method-must-be-overridden-in-proguard-opti), tried removing all -dontwarns, but it prints no further information.

Answer (score 0):

In project.properties, I had:

```
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
```

instead of correct entry:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Silly error! But so hard to track with "obfuscated" Proguard messages :)